# Использование библиотеки CommandLineParser (v2.4.3), взаимоисключаемость флагов

Tags: c#, .net

я пытаюсь использовать в своем консольном приложении библиотеку [Command Line Parser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) - самый популярный NuGet пакет для этого.

Мне требуеться реализовать взаимоисключаемость параметров согласно этой схеме: write `(-md [-p|-s] [-t]) | (-txt [-v])` где | - означает "Или", а "[]" - возможные флаги, я знаю, что я могу использовать в  аттрибуте Options параметр SetName, но это позволяет мне отделить только `(-md [-p|-s] [-t]) от (-txt [-v])`, есть идеи?

Пример класса для данного verb:

```
 [Verb("write", HelpText = "Writes output to the next pipeline step.")]
class WriteOptions
{
    private const string MdSetName = "MDSet";
    private const string TxtSetName = "TxtSet";

    private bool _hasToSetAllPass;
    private bool _hasToSetAllSkipped;

    [Option("md", SetName = MdSetName)]
    public bool IsMdTable { get; set; }

    [Option('p', SetName = MdSetName)]
    public bool HasToSetAllPass
    {
        get => _hasToSetAllPass;
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                if (_hasToSetAllSkipped)
                {
                    throw new Exception()
                    // 
                }
            }
            _hasToSetAllPass = value;
        }
    }

    [Option('s', SetName = MdSetName)]
    public bool HasToSetAllSkipped
    {
        get => _hasToSetAllSkipped;
        set => _hasToSetAllSkipped = value;
    }

    [Option('t', SetName = MdSetName)]
    public bool HasToBeAddedToTemplate { get; set; }

    [Option("txt", SetName = TxtSetName)]
    public bool IsTxt { get; set; }

    [Option('v', SetName = TxtSetName)]
    public bool IsVerbose { get; set; }

    [Value(0)]
    public string VerbValue { get; set; }

    [Value(1)]
    public IEnumerable<string> AssembliesNames { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Я задавал похожий вопрос в английской версии: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339582/easy-way-to-allow-options-only-when-other-is-present-using-commandlineparserlibr

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле все оказалось совсем легко, оставлю ответ для таких же как и я:
парсер при инициализации полей "съедает" исключения, выдавая то же что и про других ошибках парсинга, следовательно, достаточно выбрасывать исключение из `set` при неподдерживаемых случаях.

```
[Option('p', SetName = MdSetName]
public bool HasToSetAllPass
    {
        get => _hasToSetAllPass;
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                if (_hasToSetAllSkipped)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use --s and --p same time");
                }
            }

        _hasToSetAllPass = value;
    }
}

[Option('s', SetName = MdSetName]
public bool HasToSetAllSkipped
{
    get => _hasToSetAllSkipped;
    set
    {
        if (value)
        {
            if (_hasToSetAllPass)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot use --s and --p same time");
            }
        }

        _hasToSetAllSkipped = value;
    }
}
```